# How to change the date Format in android

Tags: android

I have date in this format 2015-06-23T00:05:00+00:00 in string and Now I want to convert it in 2015-06-23 format and save that format in string.

Comment: `> 100` answers already available in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Very common question-
Please see this,

```
        Calendar c5 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf5 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String strdate5 = sdf5.format(c5.getTime());
```